# "Стоимость ужина: с, на или за человека". Как правильно?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

*Стоимость ужина: 500 рублей **со** (**на** или **за**) взрослого, 300 рублей **с** (**на** или **за**) ребенка.*

Какой предлог поставить? Есть ли разница?

Answer (score 2):

**Стоимость** такого ужина *установлена в размере* столько-то **для** взрослого и столько-то **для** ребёнка [установлена для кого].

При коллективном ужине по системе шведского стола его **стоимость** *составляет* столько-то (в расчёте) **на** (одного) человека.

За ужин по системе шведского стола *взимается* **плата** в размере таком-то **с** одного человека и таком-то **за** ребёнка (с сопровождающего его взрослого) [**с** кого и **за** кого берётся плата].

В примере из вопроса нестрогий контекст (нет глаголов) допускает гибкость: можно трактовать стоимость одновременно как установленную **для** взрослого едока сумму (**стоимость** ужина для него), и как **плату**, взимаемую с него же **за** ребёнка (вариант "*для ребенка*" создаёт нежелательное впечаление, что "для ребёнка ужин обойдётся во столько-то").

> Стоимость ужина: 500 рублей **для** взрослого, 300 рублей **за** ребенка.

Answer (score 1):

Я думаю, все зависит от того, что в данном случае означает слово "ужин". Если это набор блюд, предназначенный для одного человека, то "500 рублей для взрослых, 300 рублей для детей". Если же имеется в виду коллективный ужин и его суммарная стоимость, то она вычисляется из расчета "500 рублей за (каждого) взрослого, 300 рублей за (каждого) ребенка".

Answer (score 0):

**Стоимость ужина: 500 рублей для взрослых, 300 рублей для детей.**

Пример из Нацкорпуса;

Стоимость для взрослых ― 2800 руб, для детей до 12 лет ― 2600 руб. [Рождественские праздники на родине русского Деда Мороза! (2005)]

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

**Вопрос был о стоимости,** а существительное ***стоимость*** управляет  следующими падежами: **стоимость (чего) для (кого)**, стоимость ужина для человека (для взрослого или для ребенка).

В этой теме могут использоваться **другие существительные и другие предлоги**: **ПЛАТА** за ужин **с человека или за человека**,  **РАСЧЕТ**   **на одного человека** (стоимость ужина при/в расчёте на одного человека)